# how is a node link defined in python?

Tags: python, node-editor, shader-nodes

I'm making an automatic baking script for my procedural system, and I need the script to remove and then re-make a handful of node connections in a particular order as the components are baked.

Problem I'm having is that I can't find how Blender wants the node links defined.

```
mat.node_tree.links.remove(diffuse.outputs[0], baked_BSDF.inputs[0])
```

Gives me this:

```
TypeError: NodeLinks.remove(): takes at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

Every variation of such that I've tried tells me that it's expecting a 'node link type' but it's not getting it.
If I want to make a new link this works just fine:

```
mat.node_tree.links.new(diffuse.outputs[0], baked_BSDF.inputs[0])
```

But not if I want to remove one. So then how is a `Node link` defined in python, after it's been made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [NodeLinks(bpy_struct) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeLinks.html)

> new(*input*, *output*, *verify_limits=True*
> )
>
> Add a node link to this node tree
>
> Parameters
>
> - **input** ([`NodeSocket`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html#bpy.types.NodeSocket),
>   (never None)) – The input socket
> - **output** ([`NodeSocket`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html#bpy.types.NodeSocket),
>   (never None)) – The output socket
> - **verify_limits** (*boolean* *,* *(* *optional* *)*) – Verify Limits, Remove existing links if connection limit is exceeded
>
> ---
>
> [`NodeLink`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeLink.html#bpy.types.NodeLink)
> | remove(*link*
> )
>
> remove a node link from the node tree
>
> Parameters
>
> **link** ([`NodeLink`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeLink.html#bpy.types.NodeLink),
> (never None)) – The node link to remove

The error tells you that `NodeLinks.remove(): takes at most 1 arguments, got 2`. You are feeding it two arguments instead of one, and they are sockets instead of links. Hence, it doesn't work.
NodeLinks.new() works with these two arguments because it is designed to create a link from two sockets, so feeding it two sockets make sense.

So, assuming this is your setup:

[image: setup]

```py
mat = bpy.data.materials["Material Name"]
linkToDelete = mat.node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].links[0]

mat.node_tree.links.remove(linkToDelete)
```

Result:

[image: result]

Note that in the second line, I am referring to the first input of the `Diffuse BSDF` node (programming languages count from zero, so first is actually "0"), then the first link in that input.

Comment: It works! I'll need to get it to use the defs in my script for streamlining, but that should be easy. So python sees links as being an extra layer of the input/output. That is good to know.
Thank you!

Comment: BPY does, not Python  But yes!

Comment: Well yes, bpy, technically.